# Разработка BPM (конкретно Pega) либо автоматизированное тестирование на Java, что выбрать?

Tags: java, тестирование, автоматизация

Всем добрый!

Опишу ситуацию.
22 года, 3 курс финансового факультета, школа21, имею начальные навыки и знания в разработке. Если конкретно: *С, Java, Sql, html, git, maven*. Понимаю суть ООП, concurrency/collections/немного stream api, умею работать с основными структурами данных и понимаю различия между ними, в том числе "из под капота", unix пользователь (свободно работаю в терминале).

Около месяц назад осознал, что хотелось бы двигаться в более быстром темпе и получать знания на реальном проекте непосредственно в работе. Стажировка на позиции интерна java, как мне показалось, может весьма сильно этому поспособствовать. Собственно разослав резюме и пройдя несколько собеседований, имею потенциально два пути для дальнейшего развития.

**Первый:** стажер автоматизация тестирования (месячное обучение и подписание контракта на минимум год работы в сфере тестирования). Из плюсов - стабильность и хорошая зп(по словам hr). Из минусов - не совсем уверен, что это нужное направление, которое даст необходимое развитие и навыки (изначально хотелось бы развиваться как разработчик) и невозможность уйти ввиду обязательств.

**Второй:** стажер в разработку bmp на платформе pega. Из плюсов (как я вижу) обучение в сфере разработки и отличный по отзывам от знакомых работодатель. Не уверен на счет стека используемых в этом, полагаю, узком все же направлении (pega, bpm) и насколько эти навыки будут актуальны (возможно я заблуждаюсь, скорей всего).

Конкретно вопросы:

1. Что такое разработка в сфере bpm? Как она коррелирует с общепринятым
   стеком (spring, hibernate и тд)?
2. Много ли навыков можно получить в АТ актуальных для дальнейшего развития в разработке? Не произойдет ли застоя за год в плане развития? Какой процент времени автоматизатор работает непосредственно с кодом по отношению к остальной рутине (насколько я знаю ручные тестировщики код не пишут совсем).
3. Стоит ли претендовать на позицию тестировщика и заложить на это год, чтобы далее претендовать на позицию джуниор-разработчика? Или же лучше получить опыт в бпм разработке? Также есть вариант еще полгода потратить на изучение фреймворков, технологий и далее уже искать вакансии джуна без опыта.

Вопрос, какой путь выбрать и куда двигаться дальше висит надо мной уже долгое время и однозначного ответа до сих пор нет. Надеюсь на помощь от людей, которые прошли уже некий путь и могут со своим багажом знаний и опыта дать рекомендацию куда двигаться. Важное дополнение: полученные навыки являются более приоритетным фактором нежели сумма зп.

Спасибо всем откликнувшимся!

пс
не судите строго если где-то написал чушь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути, вы задаете вопросы, на которые ответ можете знать только вы.

> Опишу ситуацию. 22 года, 3 курс финансового факультета, школа21, имею начальные навыки и знания в разработке. Если конкретно: С, Java, Sql, html, git, maven. Понимаю суть ООП, concurrency/collections/немного stream api, умею работать с основными структурами данных и понимаю различия между ними, в том числе "из под капота", unix пользователь (свободно работаю в терминале).

Ничего из этого не говорит о вас как о разработчике. У вас есть законченные проекты? Проекты в публичном доступе? Если есть, то уже хорошо. А просто быть знакомым с Java это, по сути, ничего не значит.

> и невозможность уйти ввиду обязательств

Вас там к батарее привяжут? Трудовой договор как подписывается, так и может быть прекращен в любой момент.

> Что такое разработка в сфере bpm? Как она коррелирует с общепринятым стеком (spring, hibernate и тд)?

Спросите там, где вам предлагают этим заниматься.

> Много ли навыков можно получить в АТ актуальных для дальнейшего развития в разработке?

Это специфично для каждого проекта. Есть такая профессия - SDET (Software developer engineer in Test), но есть и просто набиватели юнит тестов. В общем, спрашивайте детали там, где вам это предлагают. Но имейте ввиду, что SDET и SDE таки немного разные профессии.

> Не произойдет ли застоя за год в плане развития?

На это только вы можете ответить. Если вы кроме клепания тестов ничего делать не собираетесь, то произойдет.

> Какой процент времени автоматизатор работает непосредственно с кодом по отношению к остальной рутине

В автоматизаторы обычно вырастают из прокаченных мануальщиков. Они, помимо азов программирования, разбираются также в управлении качеством ПО. Чтобы быть хорошим автоматизатором, недостаточно просто уметь кодить.

> Стоит ли претендовать на позицию тестировщика и заложить на это год, чтобы далее претендовать на позицию джуниор-разработчика?

Стоит ли учить ухо-горло-нос, если вы собираетесь стать стоматологом?

> Также есть вариант еще полгода потратить на изучение фреймворков, технологий и далее уже искать вакансии джуна без опыта

Что вам мешает работать и учиться параллельно?

Вы просите рекомендаций - я вам их дам немного.

1. Каждый разработчик рано или поздно упирается в то, что ему надо выучить основы Computer Science. Если вы расчитываете быть кем то бОльшим, чем формошлепом, вам надо знать основы. Это алгоритмы\структуры данных, паттерны\архитектуры, базы данных, микросервисы, всякие подходы типа TDD\DDD, CI\CD - что такое и зачем оно надо, и т.д.
2. Знание самих технологий может быть бонусом для джуниора, но не является обязательным для мидла\сеньора. Предполагается, что если мидл\сеньор сейчас пишет на Java, а нужно сделать проект на Typescript+Nodejs+React, то мидл\сеньор сам в состоянии найти материалы, ознакомиться и запилить нужный проект. Особенно такие ожидания от сеньора. Например, я сам менял стек с бекенда на десктоп, потом с десктопа на немного фронтенд, потом с десктопа и фронта на микросервисы и облака, прыгая при этом с C# на Node и потом на Java.
3. Если вы хотите стать разработчиком - идите и разрабатывайте. Если хотите стать тестировщиком - тестируйте. Если хотите развиваться - делайте это не только на работе. На работе вам могут пообещать одно, а выдать потом легаси лапшу.
4. Для успешного развития нужны цель, план и ментор. Или хотя бы две вещи из этого. Если у ваc нет цели и нет плана, то вы по сути сами не знаете, чего хотите.
5. Различие между джуниором\мидлом\сеньором не столько в знании технологий, сколько в опыте работы с проектами. И вот почему:

   - Критерии хорошего кода более-менее похожи во всех языках
   - Все фреймворки построены на примерно одних и тех же паттернах
   - Проекты, их организация, построена на одних и тех же принципах и методиках в своем большинстве. Не важно на чем пишет команда, но если они говорят, наприме, что они используют SCRUM\agile\waterfall, CI\CD и багтрекер, то сеньор уже примерно понял 90% от организации проекта.
   - Еще 100500 ньюансов никак не связанных к конкретной технологией.

Comment: Это не трудовой договор. Это скорее некая подушка, которая защищает компанию от людей, который получат в ней опыт и образование в сфере и срулят спустя пару месяцев. Это слова hr. Подписывать его нужно на стадии обучения т.е еще до подписания трудового. 

Так или иначе спасибо вам за этот текст, он действительно ценен.

Comment: @witi HR не является вашим другом. HR не действует в ваших интересах. Никакие устные соглашения с HR не имеют юридической силы. Важно только то, что вы подпишите, потому внимательно читайте тркдовой договор. HR может лить вам в уши все, что ему захочется, но это все не важно, если оно не отражено в бумажках, что вы подпишете.